# column list in a method of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am not able to provide the list of columns to be returned in the csv file.

```
trans.to_csv('study10.csv' , encoding='utf-8', columns = [("reg_no", "st_name", "c_six_to_ten", "values")] )

KeyError: "[[('reg_no', 'st_name', 'c_six_to_ten', 'values')]] are not in ALL in the [columns]"
```

How do I select columns to be saved to csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
trans.to_csv('study10.csv' , encoding='utf-8', columns = ["reg_no", "st_name", "c_six_to_ten", "values"] )
```

What you tried was a list with a single tuple